# Limit method scope, avoid global scope

Tags: ruby

I would like to have a way to define methods locally. For example to write some calculations, like python notebook, when you don't want to pollute global scope.

Is there a way to limit method scope, like in the code below?

```
begin
  def some
  end

  some
end

some # <= Should'n work here
```

Comment: That's what modules and classes are for. If you define things in the top-level binding, then they are going to be available to most things that inherit from the top level.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`def` attaches the method to whatever class is in scope. For top-level methods, that is `Object`. Since that is the base class of everything, it makes the method available everywhere.

To prevent that, you need to introduce a new scope, for example by opening a `class` or `module`:

```rb
module A
  def self.foo
    puts "Hi!"
  end

  foo # Hi!
end

foo # undefined local variable or method `foo' for main:Object (NameError)

class B
  def foo
    puts "Hey!"
  end

  new.foo # Hey!
end

B.new.foo # Hey!
foo # still NameError
```

Note that `def` alone does not change the scope for further `def`s:

```rb
class C
  def foo
    def bar
      puts "Wat"
    end
  end
end

C.new.bar # Wat
```

You could instead use a lambda, which is a method-like object stored in a local variable and thus follows the local variable scoping rules:

```rb
class D
  def foo
    bar = lambda do
      puts "Heyo!"
    end
    bar[]
  end
end

D.new.foo # Heyo!
D.new.bar # undefined method `bar' for #<D:0x0000000105f04280> (NoMethodError)
```

The downside is that lambdas work differently in other ways such as how they handle `return` and method parameters, so it can be nontrivial to convert a method into a lambda.